# How to let a javascript method return an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to return for example [1,2] from a function. How do I do that?

Comment: You should first read a bit of doc about Javascript

Comment: what is [1,2] supposed to be?

Comment: some decent javascript starting resources: [fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript), and some [video tutorials](http://learn.appendto.com/lessons)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return values in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887386/how-to-return-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

```
function dummy() {
    return [1,2];
}
```

Comment: Do I detect a hint of sarcasm in the function name?

Comment: Maybe I should have added the code:

function intersect(line1,line2) {
 var point = {};
 point.x = ( line2.b - line1.b ) / ( line1.a - line2.a );
 point.y = ( line1.a * point.x ) + line1.b;
 return ???;
}

So I want to return point.x and point.y returned as an array...

Comment: @user1274143 you practically answered your question on your own. What about returning `point`?

Comment: ... return [point.x, point.y];

Comment: @Dicko declare point as following `var point = [];`and then `return point;`

Comment: @Dicko: *"Maybe I should have added..."* Yes, it's always good to 1) thoroughly describe what you want to do, and 2) provide a code example that demonstrates what you have so far. If the code in your question is too long to include, then create a reduced example, but test it to make sure it reflects the original problem.