# Print the results to my Select statement into a list in my HTML(phonegap)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

The code below is taken from the phonegap (storage and sqlite) site, however the result code only displays the result by "console.log".

I would like to print the result of this query in my html and put in the variable.

Select Statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Populate the database 
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

// Query the database
//
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

// Query the success callback
//
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
    }
}

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

</script>
```

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `document.write` instead of `console.log`

Comment: Hi Karloos, 

I like to put the results in variables

Comment: Sorry, you have to do it by yourself.
Here in example value of the function is put in the variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887386/how-to-return-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of global variable

```
var data="";
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length;
console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
var data="";
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
      data+="Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data;
   }
}
```

Comment: I can split the results into separate variables? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Divesh, with this code did not show the print in my HTML. could you help me aperece and divide the variables by field?

Comment: what exactly u mean by divide?

Comment: there is a SELECT and function, I want to put the results of the SELECT into variable in my HTML.