# Issue Creating New Object

Tags: javascript, object

```
var Contact = function(name, number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

Contact.prototype.greet = function() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.name + " " + this.number;
};

function createContact(newName, newNumber) {
    var newName = new Contact(newName, newNumber);
}

var tyler = new Contact("Tyler", "555-555-5555");
var mike = new Contact("mike", "555-555-5555");

createContact("steve", "555-555-5555");

alert(steve.name);


$("#addButton").click(function() {
    steve.greet();
});
```

I am having an issue with the above code. The issue I am having is with the createContact function. What I am trying to accomplish is to write a function that will eventually be based on user input that creates a new contact with a name and a number. I also want the name of the new Contact object to be the name of the newName, hence var newName = new Contact. Using the createContact function as it stands now does not accomplish that. I can create a new Contact object directly like I did with the "tyler" and "mike" Contacts, but not through the function.

I have tried to find the answer on my own, but have had no luck. I don't really know what I should be searching for at this point, so I'm just stuck.

Also, am I using the word "object" wrong when I say I "created a tyler object of the Contact object"?

Thanks!

Comment: You never create a `steve` variable to hold the contact like you do with `tyler` and `mike`

Comment: `var newName` is a local variable and not a global one.

Comment: Just return the variable created in `createContact` .. pls see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887386/how-to-return-values-in-javascript  .. `Custom Object` section

Answer (score 1):

That would be a very unusual function. You can do it, though, by having an object that all of these will live in (which can be the global object if you really want it to be, but I wouldn't recommend it), then:

```
function createContact(newName, newNumber) {
    theObject[newName] = new Contact(newName, newNumber);
}
```

So for instance:

```
var contacts = {};

function createContact(newName, newNumber) {
    contacts[newName] = new Contact(newName, newNumber);
}

createContact("steve", "555-555-5555");
alert(contacts.steve.name);
```

Or using globals, via the `window` global:

```
function createContact(newName, newNumber) {
    window[newName] = new Contact(newName, newNumber);
}

createContact("steve", "555-555-5555");
alert(steve.name);
```

Again, though, I'd discourage you from using globals. The global namespace is already **very** crowded.

---

Of course, again, this is a very unusual function. The normal thing would be to just do it yourself:

```
var steve = createContact("steve", "555-555-5555");
```

or even

```
var steve = new Contact("steve", "555-555-5555");
```

But you said you knew how to do that, so...

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of JavaScript. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @TylerHines Why do you want to name your variables as a parameter in the function? A better way would be simply not to do so.

Comment: @TylerHines: `var steve = new Contact("steve", "555-555-5555");` would be the normal way to do it. I'd probably call that "better," but that's an opinion...

Comment: Ideally what I want to do is create these based on user input, so I wouldn't know what the name of the contact would be. Think of it as just a regular address book where someone would enter a name and then add the contact to the address book.

Comment: @TylerHines But that would be stored in the `variable.name`, you don't need to have the `variable` part be the same as the `name`. For the user it doesn't matter how the variables are named.

Comment: @TylerHines: For that use case, my first example is the way to go (or just be even more direct: Assuming `name` has `"steve"`: `contacts[name] = new Contact(name, number);`), since (as Spencer says0 you wouldn't be referring to these with a specific variable anyway. Instead, you refer to the collection of them (`contacts` in my example), indexing into it with a string.

Answer (score 0):

How about like returning the instance from within `createContact` method.

```js
var Contact = function(name, number) {
  this.name = name;
  this.number = number;
}

Contact.prototype.greet = function() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.name + " " + this.number;
};

function createContact(newName, newNumber) {
  return new Contact(newName, newNumber); // I return the instance here
}

var tyler = new Contact("Tyler", "555-555-5555");
var mike = new Contact("mike", "555-555-5555");

var steve = createContact("steve", "555-555-5555");

alert(steve.name);
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to omit the `var steve = ` part with the `createContact()` function.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is with this modification :

```js
function createContact(newName, newNumber, context) {
    var ctx = context || this;
    ctx[newName] = new Contact(newName, newNumber);
    return ctx[newName];
}
```

```js
var Contact = function(name, number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

function createContact(newName, newNumber, context) {
  var ctx = context || this;
  ctx[newName] = new Contact(newName, newNumber);
  return ctx[newName];
}

createContact("Tyler" , "555-555-5555");
createContact("mike"  , "555-555-5555");
createContact("steve" , "555-555-5555");

alert( Tyler.name + ' | ' + mike.name + ' | ' + steve.name );
```