# Getting a variable from a function and running it in an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I have a function in which calculates price. The variable `totalPrice` calculates the total of a selection. I then write `totalPrice` to a div.

My issue is that I am running a change event on the body and I am trying to run the `calcTotalPrice` function within the change event and then trying to access the `totalPrice` variable, but it gives me the variable not defined error.

How can I get the adjusted `totalPrice` variable from my function and run it in an event?

```
function calcTotalPrice() {
        var totalPrice = 0;
        var discountPrice = 0;

        if (package1.is(':checked') && package2.is(':checked')) {
            $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function () {
                var calSoloPrice = ($(this).data('solo-price'));
                var calCombinedPrice = ($(this).data('combined-price'));
                totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('combined-price'));
                discountPrice += calSoloPrice - calCombinedPrice;
            });
            $('.tp-pack-check:checked').each(function () {
                var tpSoloPrice = ($(this).data('solo-price'));
                var tpCombinedPrice = ($(this).data('combined-price'));
                totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('combined-price'));
                discountPrice += tpSoloPrice - tpCombinedPrice;
            });
            $('#package-review-savings').html("<div class='discountMed'>You will be saving $" + discountPrice + " per order by bundling your product package.</div>");
        }
        else {
            if (package1.is(':checked')) {
                $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function () {
                    totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('solo-price'));
                });
            }
            if (package2.is(':checked')) {
                $('.tp-pack-check:checked').each(function () {
                    totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('solo-price'));
                });
            }
        }
        $('#package-review-total').html("$" + totalPrice);
    };
$('body').on('change', function () {
        calcTotalPrice();
        console.log("Total Price" + totalPrice);
});
```

Comment: The function should return the value that it calculates, then you can assign it to a variable when you call the function.

Comment: @Barmar Well if I do this `var packagePrice = calcTotalPrice();
        console.log("Total Price - " + packagePrice);` It prints as UND.

Comment: Review [How to return values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5887386/215552) and/or read [the documentation for the `return` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Comment: @Paul LIke I said, the function should return the value. `return totalPrice;`

Comment: Gotcha! I never new that `return` pushed that variable to the function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Barmar or Mike, feel free to leave an answer.

Comment: @Paul Someone already posted an answer identical to what we said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the variable inside the function. Then it only exists on that scope.

If you remove the `var` from the definition, you would be able to access globally (although I strongly not recommend this).

The better strategy would be your function return the calculated value:

```
function calcTotalPrice() {
    var totalPrice = 0;
    var discountPrice = 0;

    if (package1.is(':checked') && package2.is(':checked')) {
        $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function () {
            var calSoloPrice = ($(this).data('solo-price'));
            var calCombinedPrice = ($(this).data('combined-price'));
            totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('combined-price'));
            discountPrice += calSoloPrice - calCombinedPrice;
        });
        $('.tp-pack-check:checked').each(function () {
            var tpSoloPrice = ($(this).data('solo-price'));
            var tpCombinedPrice = ($(this).data('combined-price'));
            totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('combined-price'));
            discountPrice += tpSoloPrice - tpCombinedPrice;
        });
        $('#package-review-savings').html("<div class='discountMed'>You will be saving $" + discountPrice + " per order by bundling your product package.</div>");
    }
    else {
        if (package1.is(':checked')) {
            $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function () {
                totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('solo-price'));
            });
        }
        if (package2.is(':checked')) {
            $('.tp-pack-check:checked').each(function () {
                totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('solo-price'));
            });
        }
    }
    $('#package-review-total').html("$" + totalPrice);
    return totalPrice;
};
$('body').on('change', function () {
    var totalPrice = calcTotalPrice();
    console.log("Total Price" + totalPrice);
});
```