# Pass a value from function to other functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I need to get a value from an HTML input in a javascript function. I can successfully get the value form the HTML but I couldn't pass that from 1 function to other. And I need to pass that value to other function that is available on that javascript. I tried this code I'm getting undefined.

This is my HTML code:

```
<input value="3232" id="fn">
```

This is my script with the main function, and I can get the value from the HTML:

```
var PageKey = function(){
 var val = document.getElementById('demo').value
}

 var fun1 = function(data){

 }

 var fun2 = function(data){

 }

 var fun3 = function(data){

 }
```

This is what I tried:

```
     var fun3 = function(data){
       PageKey();
     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return values in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887386/how-to-return-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

`PageKey()` is just getting the value, but it does not return it. So, you need to add `return val;` to `PageKey()`. Then, in fun3, you can set a variable to what's returned from `PageKey()`. So, you would end up with this:

```
var PageKey = function(){
 var val = document.getElementById('demo').value;
 return val;
}

 var fun1 = function(data){

 }

 var fun2 = function(data){

 }

 var fun3 = function(data){
   var val = PageKey();
   console.log(val);
   // prints out what PageKey got
   fun1(val);
   fun2(val);
 }
```

Comment: this works fine. But the data parameter in fun1, fun2 functions should be holding the value of val

Comment: Ah, in that case we need to call fun1 and fun2 inside of fun3. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass the value that you get in `PageKey` to some other function, you need to add a `return` statement to `PageKey`.

```
var PageKey = function(){
 return document.getElementById('demo').value;
}
```

Now you'd be able to do this:

```
 var fun3 = function(data){
   var demoValue = PageKey();
  // and then do whatever with demoValue
 }
```

Comment: The data parameter in fun1, fun2 functions should be holding the value of val

Comment: Setting a parameter to hold a value in a function expression doesn't make sense... the function expression is saying "I want this logic that I'm calling `fun1` to accept some input and do something with it (and then maybe return some output)". You would then pass an argument (`data`, in this case) to it at runtime. That'd look something like `fun1(fun3(PageKey()))`, after you have added a `return` statement to `fun3`. Or, if you're sure you want a function to have a parameter stored with certain value, you would use `bind`: `var boundFun1 = fun1.bind(null, data);`

Comment: ^^ but I don't think that's what you're trying to accomplish, since you could do that in a way simpler expression. What are you trying to make happen, here, on a top level? I want to make sure I'm understanding the question

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the value

```
var PageKey = function(){
    var val = document.getElementById('demo').value
    return val;
}
```

And then

```
var fun3 = function(){
    return PageKey();
}
```