# Using function arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I need to get a value from an HTML input in a JavaScript function. I can successfully get the value form the HTML pass that value to other function that is available on that JavaScript.

This is my HTML code:

```
<input value="3232" id="demo">
```

This is my script with the main function, and I can get the value from the HTML:

```
var PageKey = function(){
  var val = document.getElementById('demo').value
  return val;
}


var fun3 = function(appData){
  var val = PageKey();
  console.log(val);
}
```

> This is what I tried. it gives me the output I want, but I want fun3 argument (appData) to hold the value. It should be able to access PageKey() from appData arguments How do I do that?

Something like:

```
var fun3 = function(appData){
var val = PageKey(appData);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a value from function to other functions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294231/pass-a-value-from-function-to-other-functions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be available in the argument to `fun3()` you need to call `fun3()` and pass in the data:

```js
function PageKey() {
  var val = "some value" // document.getElementById('demo').value
  fun3(val); // pass value to fun3
}


function fun3(appData) {
  console.log(appData);
}

PageKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

Define PageKey function like this:

```
var PageKey = function(inputEl){
  return inputEl.value;
}
```

Then you can call like this:

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('demo');
fun3(inputElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass `PageKey()` as the argument to `fun3()` like:

```
fun3(PageKey());
```

```js
var PageKey = function(){
  var val = document.getElementById('demo').value
  return val;
}

var fun3 = function(appData){
  //var val = PageKey();
  //console.log(val);
  console.log('appData: '+ appData);
}

fun3(PageKey());
```

```html
<input value="3232" id="demo" value="testValue">
```