# How can I access return value of Map from function in Node.js for Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I had read this post [How to return values in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887386/how-to-return-values-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1). But my question is how do we get the Map value if we derived it from asynchronous function like in this code below:

```js
async function exampleToken(profile) {
  let response;
  const tkAdmin = {
    admin: true,
  };
  const tkInvestors = {
    investor: true,
  };
  if (profile == 1) {
    response = {
      "token": tkAdmin,
      "code": 1,
    };
  } else if (profile == 2) {
    response = {
      "token": tkInvestors,
      "code": 2,
    };
  }
  return Promise.resolve(response);
}
```

I want to use the value from this function using this code:

```js
const response = await exampleToken(profile);
// Is this correct:
const code = response.code;
const token = response.token;
// or
const code = response["code"];
const token = response["token"];
```

Please, help me out. Any tips and trick will be great. Thank you very much for spending time to read this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct in Javascript,

- 1- Dot property accessor: object. property.
- 2- Square brackets property access: object['property']
- 3- Object destructuring: const { property } = object.

This style is named Object Dot Notation access

```
const code = response.code;
const token = response.token;
```

and this one is Object Bracket notation access

```
const code = response["code"];
const token = response["token"];
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)